# Can Paragon Surge stack with itself for the purpose of temporary feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I have a character with the [Paragon Surge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/paragon-surge) spell.

Is there anything preventing me from casting this spell multiple times to gain multiple temporary feats? I know the Int and Dex bonus wouldn't stack due to being from the same source but would that apply to the feat as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no (but mostly no).

*Paragon surge* is a transmutation spell with the [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) subtype.  Polymorph spells say:

> **You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time.** If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell. In addition, other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.

There's also [a section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects) on general "Same effect with different result" spells:

> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. **None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.**

So, the end result of applying these rules is that when you're subject to a second casting of *paragon surge*, you can choose to take a new feat or keep the old one, and *if* you take a new feat, you can revert to the old one by ending the second spell.  However, it's not a `(D)` dismissable spell, so to end it prematurely you have to voluntarily cast it at a lower caster level (and thus have a shorter duration) or to *dispel magic* on yourself.
Alternatively, you can choose to keep the original feat, and then when the first spell's duration expires, the second automatically kicks in (for whatever time it has left).

Comment: As of July 2014, it's even less ambiguous: you have to pick the same feat if you recast Paragon Surge multiple times in a single day. Much more of an errata than an FAQ, but they presented it as an FAQ. https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gh#v5748eaic9s4y